# What does redirecting to a model do?

Tags: django, redirect, django-models

I just read on SO:

> In the case of HttpResponseRedirect the first argument can only be a
>   url.
>
> redirect which will ultimately return a HttpResponseRedirect can
>   accept a model, view, or url as it's "to" argument. So it is a little
>   more flexible in what it can "redirect" to.

I've redirected to the latter two, but in what case might you redirect to a model?

Comment: Interesting question. I've never tried passing a model instance to HttpResponseRedirect, but it might implicitly call `get_absolute_url()` if the model has such a property.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the code, redirect calls [resolve_URL](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts.py#L133), which uses an object's `get_absolute_url` method if it has one. It doesn't do much sanity checking though: if the class doesn't have that method, it assumes it's being passed a URL, which will probably fail.